# Postgresql stored procedure execution error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, postgresql

I am trying to execute a Postgresql stored procedure in Excel VBA, but I am getting the following error:

> duplicatefilechecksp is procedure(); error while executing the query.

Can someone assist me to fix the issue?

PFB code :

```
Dim conSQL          As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd             As New ADODB.Command
Dim Rs              As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strErrDescSP    As String               ' Set Error Description of SP


With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = mod_General.RecturnMSSQLCon
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "duplicatefilechecksp_test"
    .Execute
End With
```

Comment: In a separate code block, please post the definition of the procedure (i.e., `CREATE OR REPLACE ...`). Why is the connection named *Recturn**MSSQL**Con* for Postgres? Please show your API connection such as ODBC driver? Redact sensitive credentials. These items will help for a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres the driver was written this way because in the past, PostgreSQL did not support procedures.

To workaround this problem and execute it as a procedure, can set CommandType to adCmdText, and set CommandText to "CALL duplicatefilechecksp(?, ?, ?)", with one question mark per parameter.